# Azure Yaml pipelines expressions; ${{}} vs $()

Tags: azure, azure-pipelines

After reading the documentation of [Expressions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/expressions?view=azure-devops) in azure yaml pipelines, the syntax of `${{}}` and `$[]` are well explained. But there is a third, namely `$()`. It is unclear to me why it is needed and what it exactly does. For example, somewhere in that documentation there is the following example

```
jobs:
- job:
  variables:
    a: $[counter(format('{0:yyyyMMdd}', pipeline.startTime), 100)]
  steps:
  - bash: echo $(a)
```

Why can't we print the variable `a` as `- bash: echo $[a]`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Why can't we print the variable a as - bash: echo $[a]?

That because suggested runtime expression variables are expanded only at runtime, it will not be evaluated.

So, if we use the syntax type `bash: echo $[a]`, it it will be the extended expression `a` instead of evaluating the value of `a`.

You could check the document Understand variable syntax for some more details:

> Azure Pipelines supports three different ways to reference variables:
>   macro, template expression, and runtime expression. Each syntax can be
>   used for a different purpose and has some limitations.
>
> Most documentation examples use macro syntax (`$(var)`). Variables with
>   macro syntax are processed during runtime. Runtime happens after
>   template expansion.
>
> You can use runtime expression syntax for variables that **are
>   expanded at runtime** ($[variables.var]).

Besides, when we get the value of static variables or predefined variables, macro will be a great choice.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It still have some difficulties with "extended expression" and an "expanded variable"? What exactly does it mean?

Comment: I've posted a related question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61468448/pass-a-variable-to-template-in-an-azure-yaml-pipeline) as well. Not sure how much it overlaps with this one, Thnx!

Comment: What is the diference between "extending" and "evaluating" here?