# Pass a variable to template in an Azure YAML pipeline

Tags: azure-pipelines, azure-yaml-pipelines

Consider the following working job from an azure yaml pipeline

```
  - job: create_slot
    dependsOn: setup
    displayName: 'Create slot'
    pool:
      vmImage: 'windows-latest'
    variables:
      slotName: $[ dependencies.setup.outputs['slot.name'] ]
    steps:
      - bash: |
          echo "Slot to be created: $(slotName)"
        displayName: 'Show slot name'
      - template: templates/create-slot.yml
        parameters:
          slot: $(slotName)
```

From the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml%2Cbatch#understand-variable-syntax) I would expect that I can replace the marco `$(slotName)` directly with the runtime expression `$[ dependencies.setup.outputs['slot.name'] ]`, which results in the following:

```
   - job: create_slot
    dependsOn: setup
    displayName: 'Create slot'
    pool:
      vmImage: 'windows-latest' 
    steps:
      - bash: |
          echo "Slot to be created: $(slotName)"
        displayName: 'Show slot name'
      - template: templates/create-slot.yml
        parameters:
          slot: $[ dependencies.setup.outputs['slot.name'] ]
```

But if you do this, the pipeline fails

[image]

From the error I get the impression that `$[ dependencies.setup.outputs['slot.name'] ]` is treaded as a string. Is it possible what I'm trying here, maybe I have incorrect syntax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no syntax issue to call `slot.name` on your `create_slot` job, here the issue should cased by the script you used in `setup` job. Since you did not share the scripts of `setup` job, I post with mine below along with some key points of it.

In your `setup` job, it should contain one script to generated **output variable** `name`. **Also**, the task which hold the variable generation process should configure the reference name `slot`.

Simple sample(**Updated**):

```
jobs:
- job: setup
  steps:
  - checkout: none
  - task: PowerShell@2
    inputs:
      targetType: 'inline'
      script: 'echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=name;isOutput=true]Staging"'
    name: slot
- job: create_slot
  dependsOn: setup
  variables:
    slotName: $[ dependencies.setup.outputs['slot.name'] ]
  steps:
  - checkout: none
  - bash: |
          echo "Slot to be created: $(slotName)"
    displayName: 'Show slot name'
```

Only this, the `create_slot` job which **depends on** the `setup` job can get the variable name by using the syntax `$[ dependencies.Job1.outputs['slot.name'] ]`:

[image]

Comment: I get the impression that you can only use `$[ dependencies.Job1.outputs['slot.name'] ]` in a variable assignment, like I did in my first code example. Because in my second example it is simply treated as a string, not as a variable. Does that make any sense?

Comment: @JeanlucaScaljeri. Yes. And my fault. I just give part of my YAML script originally.  I just updated the complete yaml which contain **setup** and **create_slot** jobs.

Comment: Thanks, it makes more sense now :)